# How to design backdrop arrow inside ionic sidemenu

Tags: ionic3

I want to keep backdrop arrow button to close side menu when user taps on the hamburger menu, I have to show an arrow to go close side menu.

This is written inside ion-menu like this

```
<div class="avatarcontent">
    <img class="avatarimg" src="https://i1.wp.com/christopherscottedwards.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Generic-Profile.jpg?fit=550%2C400">
    <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label class="avatarname">Avatar Name</ion-label>
</div>
```

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

Please guide me how I can achieve this

Comment: check my answer i already answer it, and give me feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `button` instead of `ion-icon` its can done very easily. I provide an example for closing side menu using button tap

```
<button ion-button menuClose icon-only>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Ya i have tried that one initially i have some problem with alighnment but its working now thank you so i have used margin property for proper alighnment. Thank you.